# Unable to add a Copernicus WMS to QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, wms, copernicus

I am trying to add the following WMS to QGIS:

https://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/high-resolution-image-mosaic/very-high-resolution/vhr-2012

It is published by ArcGIS for Server and here is the URL:

https://copernicus.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/rest/services/GioLand/VeryHighResolution2012/MapServer

Adding it to ArcGIS as an *ArcGIS Server* or a *WMS Server* works perfectly fine.

However, I am unable to connect to it in QGIS (2 + 3).

I've tried loading it with the buttons *Add WMS/WMTS Layer* and *Add ArcGIS MapServer Layer*, but keep getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me as ArcGIS MapServer Layer. What does QGIS tell you?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the error. Did you use the URL exactly as stated above?

Comment: Works for me too. QGIS 3.2, and I pasted the URL (https://copernicus.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/rest/services/GioLand/VeryHighResolution2012/MapServer) into the URL box of the ArcGIS Map Server Connection dialog, and named it "Copernicus"

Comment: Can you connect to any ArcGIS Map Server services from your QGIS, or is it just that one? How about other WMS servers? Is it a problem with `https` connections or does it apply to `http` too? Do you need to configure a network proxy for your local network?

Comment: Yes, https://copernicus.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/rest/services/GioLand/VeryHighResolution2012/MapServer works fine for me. QGIS 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work by using http instead of https.

So instead of using the URL that you find on the Copernicus website:

```
https://copernicus.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/services/GioLand/VeryHighResolution2012/MapServer/WMSServer?
```

you can also use:

```
http://copernicus.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/services/GioLand/VeryHighResolution2012/MapServer/WMSServer?
```

Answer (score 3):

The URL you give is not a WMS URL, despite it working for you in ArcGIS.  The WMS URL for the service is at:

```
https://copernicus.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/services/GioLand/VeryHighResolution2012/MapServer/WMSServer?
```

I can load this service URL in QGIS 3 as below:

[image: Copernicus WMS in QGIS 3]

---

So I looked again and it wasn't working for me, and then I realised that when looking at the service initially I had Fiddler (proxy) open to look at the requests being made...

So there does seem to be some issue going on here with using this HTTPS service and QGIS.

I am able to run another HTTPS WMS service (https://inspire.caris.nl/server/services/ows/view/map/unclos-zones-noordzee_IVS?) without the proxy on QGIS so the issue appears to be with the SSL handshake between QGIS and the Copernicus WMS server.

The choice of inspire.caris.nl as a test is not a coincidence, it's because the Caris server is listed in the QGIS > Options > Authentication > Manage Certificates > Servers (Server certificate exceptions) dialog.   So it might be worth added the Copernicus certificate here and having a play with the options to see if you can get around the issue.

It's good to know that there is an HTTP alternative that works, but really you'd expect the HTTPS version to work too.

I'm guessing it works for Fiddler as the proxy because FiddlerRoot is regarded as a trusted authority.

Comment: I tried this as well but it is not working. I am wondering if it is somehow linked to our network; but then again, it works in ArcGIS... I will try from home tonight and check!

Comment: Maybe you need to add a proxy setting in Qgis that is already set in arc

Comment: Ahhh, I figured it out! It works using http instead of https

Comment: Sounds more like a problem in the operating system's certificate store then.